# Multiple database row values in single variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am adding all names in to single variable but it is showing only one value last one.

my code is:

```
include 'dbconnect.php';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookedtates WHERE SID='$ServiceHosterIdv' AND BOOKEDDATE='$q'");
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookedtates WHERE SID='$ServiceHosterIdv' AND BOOKEDDATE='$q'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$csk = "'".$row['NAME']."',";
}
echo $csk;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No u just assign variable use it to plus add a "." before equtaion

```
  $csk .= "'".$row['NAME']."',";
```

But I would suggest to use array so u can use for JS(if ajax) or php for more flexible things

```
$csk = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$csk[] = array($row['NAME']);
}
echo $csk; //for ajax use echo json_encode($csk);
```

Comment: i have used this but it is displaying only "array"

Comment: try print_r($csk); You shold get it but to output the array you need loop

Answer (score 0):

just test with

```
include 'dbconnect.php';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookedtates WHERE SID='$ServiceHosterIdv' AND BOOKEDDATE='$q'");
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookedtates WHERE SID='$ServiceHosterIdv' AND BOOKEDDATE='$q'");
$csk = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $csk .= "'".$row['NAME']."',";
}
echo $csk;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the variable to the value of `$row['NAME']` on each iteration of the loop.

What you need to do is append the variable to the end of `$csk`:

```
$csk .= "'".$row['NAME']."',";
     ^---- notice the extra . here
```

The extra `.` indicates that you want to append the value to `$csk`.